# Jquery - change event firing on page load

Tags: jquery

I have select controls on a HTML page and using Jquery to
set change event.

But the event fires on the page load and does not fire when
I try to change values in the select controls.

Any ideas why?

```
$(function() {
    $('select[id^=Start], select[id^=Finish], select[id^=Lunch]').change(CalculateHours($(this)));
});
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong.

By writing `change(CalculateHours($(this))`, you are *calling* the `CalculateHours` function and passing its return value to jQuery's `change` method as if it were a function.  You would only write this if your function returned another function and you wanted to addd the returned function as an event handler.

You need to write `.change(function() { CalculateHours($(this)); })`

Answer (score 2):

You are attempting to bind the result of CalculateHours to tthe change event. Try this instead.

```
$(function() {
    $('select[id^=Start], select[id^=Finish], select[id^=Lunch]').change(function() { 
        CalculateHours($(this)); 
    });
});
```