# JQuery event handler executing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some html on my page, and in my head I have `$("#someelement").click(alert("click"));`. Whether #someelement exists or not, when I load the page for some reason the alert goes off. However, it doesn't execute when I have `$("#someelement").click(function(){alert("click")});`. Why is that?

Comment: Did you wrap that in $(document).ready() ?

Comment: Good question. I have tried it with and without that, and both ways the result is the same.

Comment: @Praveen what code? All I have is an element with the id "someelement" and the code that you can see above.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2204647/jquery-change-event-firing-on-page-load

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert("foo")` will always alert foo immediately, it does not return a function that you can pass as an event handler. You need to pass a function into the jQuery event binding method instead.

```
$("#someelement").click(function(){
    alert("click");
});
```

Additionally, if this code is in the `<head></head>`, it needs to be wrapped in `$(document).ready()`.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#someelement").click(function(){
        alert("click");
    });
});
```

---

`alert` is a method defined on the `window` object, such as, `window.alert`. It expects one parameter that is a string, and it must be a member of the window object. placing `("string")` after `alert`, such as `alert("string")` will execute that function, resulting in the popup window with `"string"`. The same thing happens when you place `alert("string")` as a parameter to a function, a popup window happens when said code runs.

Comment: Thanks. Just out of interest, how come that is so?

Comment: because `alert("Foo")` does not return a function. `$.fn.click()` requires a function to be passed as it's first parameter. It's just how JavaScript works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#someelement").click(function(){alert("click")});
});
```

Here is a working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HwfZF/)